# Same project different machines, only getting the error on new machine

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine

I am working on a project that uses angular and typescript.  On my old dev machine everything works fine but I have recently purchased a new one and have started to set things up.  Note, its the same project, pulled from our Git repo.  For both machines I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

Running the build task everything works correctly on both machines
Running the unit tests on the old machine works fine, running it on the new machine it complains about loads of TS2345 errors, which are actually valid, i.e. some of the objects in the unit tests are not fully setup (missing properties etc) since its only testing a specific unit of code.

My question is, why the discrepancy between the 2 machines? They are both using the same:

- OS (Windows 10)
- Software: Visual Studio Code
- Project: same branch from git repo
- TypeScript version: 3.7.3

Does anyone have any pointers?  I would like to ignore the errors as my old machine seems to be doing...

Comment: Same versions of Node? How did you install the dependencies (`npm ci` is the cleanest way, as it removes `node_modules/` and does it all from the lockfile)?

Comment: did you run `npm install` to generate node modules in your second computer?

Comment: yes, we do have a lockfile and I am doing npm ci to do a clean install (even though it should have been the cleanest of installs since its a new machine etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my CI/CD pipeline. Locally things worked, but the pipeline was failing on Typescript errors I couldn't observe during development.

In my case I didn't notice the package was installed using `npm i` in the CI/CD pipeline, while I was using `yarn install`. There was no `package-lock.json` in the Git repository.

This resulted in the CI/CD machine installing different packages than what I had using Yarn.

I guess having versions pinned in `package.lock` would prevent this issue from happening, but at this stage I don't do that.

So to form this to an answer:

Check you're using the same package manager on both ends, don't mix `yarn` with `npm`.